# Iterating List of lists- Return only one list out of four lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to check whether any of two values at the same index for two lists of numbers is at least sixty. Here is my code:

```
def list_list(x,y): 
    z=zip(x,y)
    l=[list(x) for x in z]
    print(l)
    for el in l:
        print(el)       
        if el[0]>=60 or el[1]>=60:
            el.append('pass')
            return el
        else:
            el.append('fail')
            return el


print(list_list(x=[28, 59, 22, 5],
    y=[59, 85, 55, 60]))
```

When I run this code it only returns `[28,59,'fail']` other remaining lists are not returned. It should also return `[59, 85, 'pass']`, `[22, 55, 'fail']` and
 `[5, 60, 'pass']`.

Why does my function stop after the first result?

Comment: Explain what your code is supposed to do please. As is right now, you are asking us to do full debugging of your code. Narrow down to where you think the problem is. Right off the bat, you are returning in your loop, so you definitely want to revise that.

Comment: my code should return [28,59,'fail'],  [59, 85, 'pass'], [22, 55, 'fail'], [5, 60, 'pass']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. The most blatant one is that when you say `return`, your function returns for good. None of the following lines will be executed once a function encounters a return statement.

In addition, there's no need to build the list `l` from the return value of `zip`, you can iterate over the tuples generated by `zip` directly.

There are two ways to prevent your function from prematurely returning. The first is to build a result-list to which you append the intermediary results and return the result-list at the end:

```
def list_list(x,y): 
    result = [] # make an empty list to store results

    for a,b in zip(x,y):    
        # decide pass or fail
        if a >= 60 or b >= 60:
            word = 'pass'
        else:
            word = 'fail'    
        # append to result list
        result.append([a, b, word])

    # return result list
    return result
```

Alternatively, you can construct a generator that spits out the intermediary results as they are computed:

```
def list_list(x,y):         
    for a,b in zip(x,y):    
        # decide pass or fail
        if a >= 60 or b >= 60:
            word = 'pass'
        else:
            word = 'fail'

        # yield intermediary result
        yield [a, b, word]

print(list(list_list([28, 59, 22, 5], [59, 85, 55, 60]))) # [[28, 59, 'fail'], [59, 85, 'pass'], [22, 55, 'fail'], [5, 60, 'pass']]
```

Of course, all of this could be done with a list comprehension:

```
>>> x=[28, 59, 22, 5]
>>> y=[59, 85, 55, 60]
>>> [[a,b,'pass'] if a >= 60 or b >= 60 else [a,b,'fail'] for a,b in zip(x,y)]
[[28, 59, 'fail'], [59, 85, 'pass'], [22, 55, 'fail'], [5, 60, 'pass']]
```

Final notes:

in Python2, consider using `itertools.izip` for memory efficiency instead of `zip` because you don't need the complete list of tuples from `zip`.

Consider using a better function name. `list_list` is telling me nothing about what the function is supposed to do. How about `atleast_sixty_pairs` or something like that?

Comment: Lots of thanks for your insightful solutions and alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `return` in your function, you are quitting the function.  If you go to a party and return, you aren't still at the party.  You could change `return` to `yield` in order to create a generator function, but what you probably want is to create your own list:

```
def list_list(x,y): 
    z=zip(x,y)
    l=[list(x) for x in z]
    returnlist = []
    print(l)
    for el in l:
        print(el)       
        if el[0]>=60 or el[1]>=60:
            el.append('pass')
            returnlist.append(el)
        else:
            el.append('fail')
            returnlist.append(el)

    return returnlist


print(list_list(x=[28, 59, 22, 5],
    y=[59, 85, 55, 60]))
```

Comment: Hi zondo, it does print only none nothing else.

Comment: @ohid look at the updated code, the return was added.

Comment: @ohid and if this answer helped you, make sure to accept it.

Comment: @ohid Thank zondo, he answered the question. Please accept the answer.